# mod_wsgi with Apache ignoring python-path

Tags: arch-linux, apache-httpd

I'm trying to run [mozilla-firefox-sync-server](https://aur4.archlinux.org/packages/mozilla-firefox-sync-server-git/) with apache 2.4.17-3 on my Arch Linux server, following [this guide](http://docs.services.mozilla.com/howtos/run-sync-1.5.html). Here's a part of my `/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

```
<Directory /opt/mozilla-firefox-sync-server>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ffsync.example.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/mozilla-firefox-sync-server/

    WSGIProcessGroup ffsyncs
    WSGIDaemonProcess ffsyncs user=ffsync group=ffsync processes=2 threads=25 python-path=/opt/mozilla-firefox-sync-server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/mozilla-firefox-sync-server/syncserver.wsgi
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/ffsync_custom combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/ffsync_error
</VirtualHost>
```

When I `curl ffsync.example.com`, I get a 500 error. In the log, It looks like it's running with Python 3.5 (`ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'`).

Indeed, if I replace `syncserver.wsgi` with the following sample code from the [ArchWiki page on mod_wsgi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mod_wsgi#Module_test):

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def wsgi_app(environ, start_response):
    import sys
    output = sys.version.encode('utf8')
    status = '200 OK'
    headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
               ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, headers)
    yield output

application = wsgi_app
```

I get a 200 status code with `3.5.0 (default, Sep 20 2015, 11:28:25) [GCC 5.2.0]`.

When I use the package `mod_wsgi2`, everything works correctly, but I need to use `mod_wsgi` because there's also a Python 3 WSGI application running with Apache which cannot run with `mod_wsgi2`. The [ArchWiki page on mod_wsgi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mod_wsgi#Installation) states that `mod_wsgi` should work with Python 2 and 3.

What makes the `python-path` argument in the `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive ignored?

**Update :** Having a recent version of `mod_wsgi` (4.4.21-1), I also tried using `python-home`, like so:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess ffsyncs user=ffsync group=ffsync processes=2 threads=25 python-home=/opt/mozilla-firefox-sync-server/local/
```

This time, I get a 504 error and this message in the error log (whether original or modified `syncserver.wsgi`)

```
Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'ffsyncs': /opt/mozilla-firefox-sync-server/syncserver.wsgi
```

Comment: I am looking at syncserver.wsgi in github. SHould it not have as first line #!/usr/bin/env python ? It is not there...

Comment: Neither `#!/usr/bin/env python`, `#!/usr/bin/env python2`, `#!/usr/bin/python2`, nor `#!/opt/mozilla/firefox-sync-server/local/bin/python2` in the beginning of `syncserver.wsgi` (wether the original version or my version) change anything, it is still ran with Python 3 after restarting `httpd`.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem? I am facing the very same issue at the moment

Comment: Sadly not, I have given up. Looks like Arch Linux package `mod_wsgi` is for Python 3, not Python 2. However, there's one thing I haven't tried, that is compiling `mod_wsgi` myself from the instructions on the official website. If I recall correctly, it is supposed to handle both version of Python at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried using the `WSGIPythonHome` directive? [The documentation](https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/ConfigurationDirectives.wiki) suggests that it's this directive that is used to tell Apache to use a certain Python executable. The `python-path` option to `WSGIDaemonProcess` is only for modifying the Python module search path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same `Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process` problem. Apache's main log file (not the one for that VirtualHost) showed this error:

```
Unable to change working directory to '/home/ffsync'.
Failure to configure the daemon process correctly and process left in unspecified state. Restarting daemon process after delay.
```

It turned out the home directory for `ffsync` didn't exist. Changing it to `/opt/mozilla-firefox-sync-server/` resolved the problem for me. Maybe it helps you as well!